# iPhone - Register for push notification lock iPhone running iOS3 on Release mode

Tags: iphone, debugging, release, apple-push-notifications, ios-3.x

I put the following code in "applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

...//other code
}
```

The app works fine in iOS 4, iOS 5 (DEBUG and RELEASE mode).
The app works fine in iOS 3 in DEBUG mode.
The app DOES NOT work in iOS 3 in RELEASE mode, the phone is locked when the app starts.
Please see screenshot.
 [image]
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by locked? do you mean stuck? Does it happen on a real device or only on simulator?

Comment: So borrowed 2 other iPhone running iOS 3.0 and the app works fine.
May be it happens to my device only.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I wonder if this is because you don't have a SIM card installed...

Comment: I thought so too, but the 2 iPhone I borrowed (running iOS 3) don't have SIM card either and the app works fine. Good try though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So borrowed 2 other iPhone running iOS 3.0 and the app works fine. May be it happens to my device only.